# Regularly Updating Mysql records based on importance

Tags: mysql, cron

I have a database table of items, lets call them games. each game has a release date

I run a script that selects a game at random, and updates various bits of information such as price etc from my source data. this script is on a cron to fire at regular intervals throughout the day

There are 20,000 odd game records and growing, so obviously some of these games being kept up to date are more important than others. This is mostly based on the release date, but could include data from other fields too.

Is there any way I can get my batch processing script to select a record based on this importance, without having to run through all results until each one has been updated and then start at the top?

So the frequency of updating the more important games would be higher than the less important ones?

Comment: I think you need to define the formula for the importance first. If it is just based on release date you can simply use `ORDER BY DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),release_date) DESC LIMIT xxx` in your select query. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As @Usman mentioned, you need to define a way of measuring importance that works properly.  Then, my suggestion would be to have your script update two records each time it ran.  You'd choose one of those records at random from among the "important" records, and the other one at random from among all records.

That way you would not reduce your probability of updating any given record, and at the same time you'd increase the probability of updating the important ones.

But, you know, even if you ran your random update script once a second, there's no guarantee you'd get to all 20,000 records daily. The fan of the game you don't update for a week might become annoyed that your data was stale.  It might be better to update things on a fixed schedule, or when you get new data for them, rather than randomly.